# Building a proxy server with Express and Request

Tags: node.js, express, request

I need to build a small nodejs app that receives a request as such:
http://localhost?url=http://www.someurl.com

The server needs to receive the request, download the page from given url, modify its HTML, and return it to the client (proxy?)

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // Get url from the query
    var url = decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(req.query.url));

    request(url, function(error, response, html) {
        // ...
        // DO SOME MODIFICATIONS TO THE HTML HERE
        // ...

        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

My current problem is that css/js files that have relative URLs aren't being forwarded to their origin, but instead, they're being sent to download from my server like this:
http://localhost/css/some-css-file.css
http://localhost/js/some-js-file.js

This is just part of the problem, all other resources with relative URLs, and all HTTP requests that page makes that aren't an absolute URL request, are also going to the root host which is localhost in my case.

I've done some research but couldn't quite get the whole deal of how to do this properly.
Is the pipe function what I need ? I don't quite get how to use it.

Comment: This sounds like either a proxy misconfiguration or a lack of html modification. Are you only using the proxy through that link-type interface?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.
It's obviously a misconfiguration or mis-use of the tools express/request give me.